# Execute more than one select statement using a single cursor of pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to connect to SQL Server server and execute my query, like:

```
connection=connect(...)
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
    SELECT ...
    INTO #temp_table_1
    FROM table1

    SELECT ...
    INTO #temp_table_2
    FROM #temp_table_1

    SELECT *
    FROM #temp_table_2
''')
result=cursor.fetch_all()
```

But it seems that the result equals to None, and I am wondering why. Is pyodbc only capable to return the  result of first statement?

Comment: pyodbc connector (or pymysql) doesn't allow multiple statements in a SQL call. This is an issue of engine parsing. https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#description

Comment: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of your code block and see if that helps.

Comment: @GordThompson it works, thank you!